# Spring WebClient exchangeToMono seem to return nothing

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, reactive, spring-webclient

I am consuming an external API asynchronously using Spring WebClient and use exchangeToMono(). Here is my code block:

```
`Mono<ExternalServiceResponse> externalServiceResponseMono = webClient.get()
                .header("trackingid", "abc123")
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                    if(clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ExternalServiceResponse.class);
                    }
                    else if (clientResponse.statusCode()
                            .is4xxClientError()) {
                        log.error("ErrorResponse Code from ExternalService API is: " + clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
                         return Mono.error(new RestServiceCallException(clientResponse.statusCode().getReasonPhrase()));
                    }else if (clientResponse.statusCode()
                            .is5xxServerError()) {
                        return Mono.error(new ExternalServiceCallException(clientResponse.statusCode().getReasonPhrase()));
                    }
                    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Unknown error occured while calling External Service API"));
                })
                .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(2, Duration.ofSeconds(2)).filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof ExternalServiceCallException ));`
```

Then I subscribe to Mono response as below:

```
List<Response> processedResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
externalServiceResponseMono.subscribe(res -> res.getDetails().forEach(section -> processedResponseList.add(processResponseExternalAPI(section))));
```

I am not seeing anything being subscribed from externalServiceResponseMono (even though API returns data, verified in postman). The processedResponseList is always empty.
What am I missing? Why do I see no data being subscribed from Mono?